# Navigation Bar Hidden, create own Back Button in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, back

I am trying to create my own Back-Button.
All my ViewControllers are in a Navigation Viewcontroller. But because I don't need the navigation bar I am hiding it. From the first ViewController I am coming with a button to the second ViewController. In the second ViewController I am trying to create a BackButton now on my own, but I don't know how to program the back function.

```
self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "exitSegueStats", sender: self)
```

I tried it with this line. I am coming back to the previous page, but then my Button is disabled and I don't know why.

```
let MainVC = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(identifier: "StatistikenMenu") as! StatistikViewControlelrViewController
    navigationController?.pushViewController(MainVC, animated: true)
```

And with those lines, I am coming back too, but then I create a infinity loop. So I mean I can swipe back and this should not be so.

I know it is a little bit complicate, so I would really appreciate your help, thanks.

Comment: did you try `self.navigationController?.popViewController(animated:true)`

Comment: Showing a few chunks of code won't help others to understand the issue you are facing.

Comment: thanks to Andreas Oetjen. This was helpful